# On the conceptual difference between almost sure convergence and mean convergence

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let me start by saying I'm not a mathematician, but I really need some clarification on this topic.
There are three notions (actually more than three but anyways) of convergence:

1. convergence in probability,
2. almost sure convergence,
3. convergence in mean.

As a matter of fact (it can be proven), 2. and 3. implies 1., but not vice-versa, and secondly 2. and 3. are independent of each other.

And yet, their definitions look pretty similar to one another. Apart from the proofs and lemmas and counterexamples behind all this, I can't grasp the conceptual difference. For instance, what does it mean for a process to converge according to 3. but not for 1.? What makes it to be that different from, say, another one that converges almost surely but not in mean?

I suppose 2. and 3. answer different, though related questions, but which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a sequence of random variables $X_n$, converging to $X$ in some sense. That means that "eventually", the distance between $X_n$ and $X$ is small. Where your three definitions differ is in what they mean by "eventually":

1. the distance is probably small after some fixed time
2. the distance is always small after some random time
3. the average distance is small after some fixed time

You can see that these are similar claims, but not the same. For a sense of why they differ, consider a few examples of random variables $X_n$ converging to $0$:

- Let $U$ be uniform on $[0, 1]$, and set $X_n = 1$ if $U < 1/n$, $0$ otherwise. This satisfies 1., 2. and 3.
- Let $U$ be uniform on $[0, 1]$, and set $X_n = n$ if $U < 1/n$, $0$ otherwise. This satisfies 1. and 2., but not 3.
- Let the $X_n$ be independent, $X_n = 1$ with probability $1/n$, $0$ otherwise. This satisfies 1. and 3., but not 2.
- Let the $X_n$ be independent, $X_n = n$ with probability $1/n$, $0$ otherwise. This satisfies 1., but not 2. or 3.

Since 2. implies 1., and 3. implies 1., these examples cover all possible combinations where at least one condition holds.

Comment: You used the word *time*, but I can't see a clear role played by time here. Did you mean *n*? Or are they both relevant in the definitions, in the sense you need a certain fixed $n$ *and* a time *t*?

Comment: @ric.san Yes, I'm referring to $n$ as time, e.g. as in a time series.